# vim command/comment in the end of config files

Tags: vimrc

Actually it may be offtopic, but I believe that vim users know the answer.
Earlier, in the proccess of using linux through years, I had noticed that some config files have something like "vim comment" in the end.

Like:

```
# vim: ft-conf:
```

(It is from grub-legacy cfg file)

And much more commands in different config files.
Is it related to vim? And if so, which way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is called a modeline. It is used to define file specific settings. For more info, see [`:h auto-setting`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#auto-setting) and the following parts about modelines.